# trying to get array value from models. octobercms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

i am having trouble retrieve value of an array in Model. so i have model which has repeater field. now i am trying to access the value of that repeater field from another model.

this is what i have done..

***UPDATED***

fields.yaml  in **WartaDataProfil** model

```
fields:
visimisi:
    label: 'Visi Misi'
    ---
jdwlibdh:
    label: 'Jadwal'
    oc.commentPosition: ''
    prompt: 'add'
    maxItems: '7'
    span: full
    type: repeater
    form:
        fields:
            jeniskeb:
                label: 'Jenis'
                ---
            jamibdh:
                label: 'Jam'
                ---
            kategori:
                label: 'Kategori'
                type: dropdown
                options:
                    Umum/Raya: Umum/Raya
                    Komisi/Kategorial: Komisi/Kategorial
```

> the model name **WartaDataProfil**

```
class WartaDataProfil extends Model
{
  use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

  public $timestamps = false;

  public $rules = [
  ];   
  public $table = 'mismaiti_mywarta_profil';

  protected $jsonable = ['pdtjmt','jdwlibdh','komisi','bidang'];

  public $attachOne = [

      'logogereja' => 'System\Models\File',
      'logomywarta' => 'System\Models\File'

    ];
}
```

i want to retrieve data from 'jeniskeb' field on **WartaDataProfil** to be use on another model(let say the model is **WartaRutin**) as dropdown options on one of the field, so i write these on **WartaRutin** model

fields.yaml on **WartaRutin** model

```
tabs:
fields:        
    tanggal:
        label: Tanggal            
        mode: date
        format: 'd - F - Y'
        span: storm
        cssClass: col-sm-4 col-sm-push-0
        type: datepicker
        tab: 'Minggu Ini'                            
    kebum:
        label: ''            
        prompt: 'Tambah Data'
        maxItems: '3'            
        type: repeater
        tab: 'Minggu Ini'
        form:
            fields:
                jeniskeb:
                    label: 'Kebaktian'
                    ---
                    type: dropdown
                    options: jenisKeb
                khotbah:
                    label: Pengkhotbah
                    ---
                    type: text
```

and this is **WartaRutin** model **(Updated with solution of @HardikSatsiya)**

```
class WartaRutin extends Model
{
  use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

  use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\SoftDelete;

  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
  public $rules = [    ];    
  public $table = 'mismaiti_mywarta_rutin';
  protected $jsonable = ['temakebum','rankhot','kebum','kebkom','bngmbr'];

  public function jenisKeb(){
      $jdwlibdh = WartaDataProfil::pluck('jdwlibdh');

    $jenkebOptions= [''];
    foreach($jdwlibdh as $item)  {

        // json decoding 
        $decoded = json_decode($item, true);

        print(dd($decoded));

        // manually filtering
        if($decoded['kategori'] == 'Umum/Raya') {
            $jenkebOptions[$decoded['jeniskeb']] = $decoded['jeniskeb'];      
        }
    }

    return $jenkebOptions;
}
```

Solution of @HardikSatasiya return an error

> Undefined index: kategori

print(dd($decoded))  result

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
  "jeniskeb" => "Kebaktian Umum 1"
  "jamibdh" => "07.00 WIB"
  "kategori" => "Umum/Raya"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
  "jeniskeb" => "Kebaktian Umum 2"
  "jamibdh" => "09.00 WIB"
  "kategori" => "Umum/Raya"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
  "jeniskeb" => "Kebaktian Umum 3"
  "jamibdh" => "18.00 WIB"
  "kategori" => "Umum/Raya"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
  "jeniskeb" => "Kebaktian Pemuda"
  "jamibdh" => "09.30 WIB"
  "kategori" => "Komisi/Kategorial"
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
  "jeniskeb" => "Kebaktian Remaja"
  "jamibdh" => "09.30 WIB"
  "kategori" => "Komisi/Kategorial"
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
  "jeniskeb" => "Kebaktian Tunas Remaja"
  "jamibdh" => "09.30 WIB"
  "kategori" => "Komisi/Kategorial"
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
  "jeniskeb" => "Kebaktian Anak"
  "jamibdh" => "09.30 WIB"
  "kategori" => "Komisi/Kategorial"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal approach will not work as your data is `repeater` so it will be `JSON` in database.

> code you need to put inside `WartaRutin` model

```
public function jenisKeb(){

    $jdwlibdh = WartaDataProfil::pluck('jdwlibdh');

    $jenkebOptions= [''];
    foreach($jdwlibdh as $item)  {

        // json decoding 
        $decoded = json_decode($item, true);
        foreach($decoded as $innerItem)  {

            // manually filtering
            if($innerItem['kategori'] == 'Umum/Raya') {
                $jenkebOptions[$innerItem['jeniskeb']] = $innerItem['jeniskeb'];      
            }
        }
    }

    return $jenkebOptions;
}
```

this should work let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I just notice what you suggest to be use in the same model.. while i am trying to access that model from different model..

Comment: Its a dropdown field from different that retrieve options from that model and filter base on 'kategori' field value

Comment: if you are showing form for specific model `xyz` then you had to write `dropdown` in that xyz model, with in that model you can call another model's options

Comment: or am i missing something you question is not telling full information , tell form model which data you are updating and tell from which model you want to fetch data and also do you need depended drop down or single time data population at start up only

Comment: fields.yaml <- this is of  `WartaDataProfil` model and you want to show drop-down inside it which options will come from `WartaRutin` model ok ?

Comment: No.. vice versa sir.. i want to show dropdown option  inside `WartaRutin` model  and the options come from `WartaDataProfil`

Comment: last thing `fields.yaml` <- is of `WartaRutin`  right

Comment: No.. thats `WartaDataProfil`

Comment: ok finally pelase post both `fields.yaml` file with `header with its respective model name` ( requirement is show dropdown option inside WartaRutin model and the options come from WartaDataProfil )... and form rendering is of `WartaRutin  model's fields.yaml`

Comment: i have try.. it return an error.. `Undefined index: kategori`

Comment: i have updated my question along with your solution.. and print (dd($decoded)).. for your reference..

Comment: updated answer please check new solution and let us know